# c# httpclient - disable ntlm

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, ntlm-authentication

I'm using this code to connect to a third party server.

```
using (HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    httpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    httpClientHandler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);
    using (HttpClient authClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
    {
        response = await authClient.GetAsync(authenticationUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);
        ... response processing here
    }
}
```

The third party server is an appliance, and they've turned on NTLM recently. Starting with the turning on of NTLM, my request now gets an HTTP 500 error error like this:

> type Exception report message NTLM specified. Downgraded to Basic
>   Auth (and/or SSL) but downgrade not supported. description The server
>   encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this
>   request. exception  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: NTLM
>   specified. Downgraded to Basic Auth (and/or SSL) but downgrade not
>   supported.
>     net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoProvider.negotiate(SpnegoProvider.java:146)
>     net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:271)
>     net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter.doFilter(SpnegoHttpFilter.java:229)

I'm assuming my httpclient sees that the server now supports NTLM and tries to do NTLM. Is there any way to tell my httpclient to don't even bother with NTLM?

Comment: I think the problem is that the server only supports NTLM.  The client requested a resource on the server, the server replied that NTLM authorization was required, your client replied to that saying it couldn't do NTLM, how about Basic instead?  And the server said, "Sorry" and closed the connection.  So the answer as I see it is that you can't not bother with NTLM because the server is asking for it.

Comment: That may well be.. is there a way to trace this without putting Fiddler in between (they frown upon that in production environment)?
I'd just like to make sure on my end that I can ensure my client doesn't even bother to try with NTLM but I've not found a way. Something along the lines like you can enable/disable support for SSL/TLS versions.

Comment: I find it odd that they'd complain about using Fiddler in a production environment since it runs on the client.  One option I've used a lot is Burp Suite which acts as a proxy on your client machine.  You can capture and track exactly what's getting sent between client and server.  You could also roll your own, since it's just a TCP transaction, just make a TCP connection and do the reading and writing yourself.  Or for the truly adventurous, use Telnet.

Answer (score 1):

To disable NTLM try this:

```
        var modules = AuthenticationManager.RegisteredModules;
        while (modules.MoveNext())
        {
            var module = (IAuthenticationModule) modules.Current;
            if (module.AuthenticationType == "NTLM")
            {
                AuthenticationManager.Unregister(module);
                break; 
            }
        }
```